# Automatic image creation in enterprise arhitect

Tags: enterprise-architect

We have a list of applications which are interlinked with each other. Is there a possibility to automatically get an architecture diagram in "Enterprise architect" tool if I give the inputs in an excel? For ex: In the excel

### Application    Upstream     Downstream

A              B,C            X,Y

Now in the EA I need an output like B,C are connected to A.
A is connected to X,Y. Please help me out.

Comment: No. That's not possible. You need to program that with the API.

Comment: which API can be used

Comment: Well, EA's of course, since you asked for EA.

Comment: Did you try Excel Importer of MDG Integration for Microsoft office in EA ?